# How to glob/fuzzy find a command

Tags: linux

I am curios is there a way to "glob" a command? What I mean is e.g. I know there is a command which can do something for me, but I only remember it has a word `fix` in it, and I am sure it is installed on my machine and is in my `PATH`

If I remember the first character of it, I guess I can tab my way out, but what if I don't?

Is there some way for me to find a command like this?
`$ find-command *fix*`

Comment: What you are asking us unclear. 'find / -type f -executable -name "*fix*" ' would find all files including the word fix in them that are executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apropos` may be useful. It will give you more matches (because it searches in manuals) but also short *descriptions*, which may be a good thing. Start with `apropos -s 1,8 fix`. See [`man 1 apropos`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/apropos.1.html) and read about `-r` and `-w` options.

---

If your `$PATH` does not include paths that would trigger globbing or word splitting, supply it to `find` and proceed like this:

```
find $(printf "$PATH" | tr ':' ' ') -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -name '*fix*'
```

Notes:

- `$()` unquoted on purpose;
- `-maxdepth` and `-executable` are not required by POSIX, your `find` may not support them.