# Bash Tab expansion to list all executables based on regex

Tags: command-line, bash, regex, path, bash-scripting

How can I use regex based methods to find commands available in the  `${PATH}`?

For example when I press `w` and `Tab` switch. I get a list of all commands starting with `w`. I would like to list all commands that starts with `w` but are not followed by `s`. Is it possible to use regex or some other means to do it?

Or How can I use grep to remove certain tab expansion results?

---

Note: When I am doing tab expansion, I am mainly looking for small scripts that I wrote, which have no man page. They are just available on the path.

Comment: Somewhat similar: [How to glob/fuzzy find a command?](https://superuser.com/q/1550127/432690)